# When I set image from Url to recycleView it slows down, how can I fix it?

Tags: java, android, image, android-recyclerview

I have a recycleView with 50 block. The block has two ImageView. I should set two images to every block from different URL. And when I start my program I flipping the list, my program slows down. I think it inhibits becouse of when I scroll the list recyclerView go to URL again to take images. Am I right? And how I can fix it?

It is how I set image to recyclerView from URL

```
URL newurl = new URL(imageString);
Bitmap mIcon_val = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(newurl.openConnection().getInputStream());
holder.myImageView.setImageBitmap(mIcon_val);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/lazy-load-of-images-in-listview)

Comment: My Recommendation use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) library to load images as answer below told

Comment: You can use Picasso library also

Comment: Stick with Glide V3 if you want simplicity, V4 if you want latest support + extendability and avoid Picasso since it's very opinionated. You have to adjust your code to their rules in order to make your application work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using bitmap to load images. Loading bitmap in image view is very memory consuming task.

Instead you can use third party library to load image from network URL directly.

One of these library is Glide. You just need to pass imageView and URL into it and it will load image directly.

```
Glide.with(context)
   .load("URL HERE")
   .into(imageView);
```

Even you can resize image before loading it into imageView, by doing that way, you can reduce memory consumption.

```
 RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
 requestOptions.override(120, 120);
 requestOptions.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL);

 Glide.with(context)
   .load("URL HERE")
   .apply(requestOptions)
   .into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use picasso or glide for this task-:

```
Glide.with(context).load(model.getVoucher_image()).into(holder.imageview);
```

Comment: What is "Glade" and "model"?

Comment: Glide is a library for displaying image and model.getvoucherimage is url or bitmap you want to load

Comment: import  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0' in your build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

Use Glide to load images efficiently.

**Example**
In app module `gradle` add this

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  google()
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
  annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
}
```

then usage for glide to load images from `drawable`

```
Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.image_name).into(imageView);
```

**Example**

onBindViewHolder do this

```
Glide.with(this).load(logoImage).into(holder.logo);
```